# Why does Windows Live! Messenger has a thing for XKCD?

Tags: windows-live-messenger

Just a moment ago I wanted to send a link to the [latest XKCD comic](http://www.xkcd.com/835/) through Windows Live! Messenger. I sent it just well, along with a comment, but the next second I was suddenly sharing the picture (in messenger), and the tooltip text was underneath it in a way I hadn't seen before.

So... WTF? How did this happen? Is XKCD website special somehow? Or can I make my website like that too with some special tags or something? I didn't see anything standing out in the markup.

**Added:** (Open picture for a bigger view)
[image]

Comment: a screenshot might help

Comment: @The Journeyman geek - There!

Comment: Shouldn't it be Backward Read I Think Engineers Highway? :P

Comment: @mickburkejnr - Nope. Because in this case the order of the lines is what is important (and backwards), not the order of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a new feature of msn messenger.

http://windowslive.ninemsn.com.au/messenger/article/7964857/introducing-messenger-2011

Comment: Nice! Too bad they don't explain what you should do to integrate your page with this new feature...